# Change state of a parent's component using child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI's react modal for making modal which is my child component, in the parent component, I am stating a state which hides and shows modal, and a button in the modal to close it. But that doesn't seem to work.

Link:-> https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-tereshkova-1yuhx?file=/src/childComponent.js

Comment: <Popup open={showPopUp} hidepopup={handlePopup} />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you passed as props a **state variable function**

```
<Popup open={showPopUp} hidepopup={changeShowPopUp} />
```

but need to pass your `handlePopup` function

```
<Popup open={showPopUp} hidepopup={handlePopup} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just missing invocation on the child component try to add this to the on click
onClick={() => props.hidepopup(false)}